# Configuring Automatic Login for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, login

When booting up into Ubuntu it has a dialog with the default user and an input field for a password.

How do I disable this prompt so the default user is automatically logged in?

Comment: It depends on your display manager. Look at in its config file.

Comment: Where is the config file?

Comment: On Lubuntu, I entered `autologin=user` into `/etc/xdg/lubuntu/lxdm/lxdm.conf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the official web site's documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-autologin.html.en), perform these five steps:

- Open Activities, and start typing `Users`
- Click Users to open the panel
- Select the user account you wish to have automatically logged in
- Press Unlock, and enter the user's password
- Set the "Automatic Login" switch to the "On" position.

Comment: I am running a Xenial distribution on Orange Pi, and there doesn't seem to be an Activities panel...